# How to count a specific word separated by paragraphs?

Tags: python-3.x, counter

So I want to be able to count the number of times a certain sequence such as "AGCT" appears in a document full of letters. However I don't just want the total amount in the document, I want how many times it shows up separated by ">".

So for example if the document contained: asdflkdaf**agct**alkjsdj**agct**lkdjf>asdlfkja**agct**>adjkhfhAGCTlksdjf**agct**>...

It would tell me:
2
1
1

since the sequence "AGCT" appears twice before the first ">" and once after the next one and once more after the third one and so on.

I do not know how to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Do you currently have a working script that parses for the total amount of sequences in the document? If so, whenever you read in a ">" character, just print the current total from your count variable and then set it to zero to begin counting again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of string methods and Python's llist comprehension like this: 
Split your text in paragraphs, and for each paragraph count the ocurrences of the wanted substring. It is actually more concise in Python than in English:

```
>>> mytext = "asdflkdafagctalkjsdjagctlkdjf>asdlfkjaagct>adjkhfhAGCTlksdjfagct>"
>>> count = [para.count("agc")  for para in mytext.split(">")  ]
>>> count
[2, 1, 1, 0]
```